# Define same command with different amount of parameters

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I want to define two versions of the command `\Set`, depending if I provide one or two parameters. I.e. like this:

```
\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\bigl\{ #1 \bigr\}}
\newcommand{\Set}[2]{\bigl\{ #1 \bigm| #2 \bigr\}}
```

But that doesn't work. It complains about the redefinition of the command.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't "overload" macros in TeX like functions in other programming languages.

You can either define the macro to use a normal optional argument for one of the two parameters or define a special macro which looks ahead if a opening brace follows. The `xparse` package can help you defining one:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\Set{mg}{%
    \ensuremath{\bigl\{ #1 \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\bigm| #2} \bigr\}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\Set{A}{B}
\Set{A}
\]

\end{document}
```

Here the `m` in the definition stand for *mandatory argument* and the `g` for *optional argument delimited by a TeX group*, i.e. `{}`.

Comment: I'd probably use `G{}` in the argument specification, then do the `\IfNoValueTF` test _inside_ the `\ensuremath`, including `#2` in all cases (as this will be fine with an empty default).

Comment: Thanks @Joseph, I'm a beginner with `xparse`. But the "`#2` in all cases` doesn't work because there is still `\bigm|` which must not be included in the first case.

Comment: Thanks, perfect! And that doesn't actually seem to be so complicated, why would you suggest not to use it?

Comment: @Martin: Fair point, but you could stick to `g` and so use `\IfNoValueF{#2}{\bigm| #2}`.

Comment: @Albert: I didn't say don't use it, I said defining such macros isn't that easy. But I had more the manual definition in mind. The `xparse` package simplifies things very much.

Comment: @Joseph: Indeed. I updated the code. Thanks!

Comment: @Albert: I'd also have no hesitation in recommending using `xparse` to new users. Part of the reason for it's existence is to make this sort of thing easier.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to be late to the party. Anyway, the `g` and `G` argument specifiers are deprecated.

The most natural syntax is `\Set{A}` or `\Set{A | B}` which is even easier to type than `$\Set{A}{B}$`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Set}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{|}}m }{\SetAux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\SetAux}{mm}{%
  \bigl\{%
  #1%
  \IfValueT{#2}{\bigm|#2}%
  \bigr\}%
}

\begin{document}

This is a simple set $A=\Set{1,2,3}$, but this is more
complex
\[
B=\Set{x\in C | x=x^2}.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not the most flexible solution in terms of scalability of the braces.

Comment: @Gaussler Sure, but that's what the OP wanted. This is covered elsewhere; my aim was to provide an answer that's free of `g` argument types.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two macros with the different parameter counts (and name) and invoke them within a composite macro with the desired name. Inside the new macro, call one of the two macros based on the number of parameters passed using `\IfNoValueTF`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%Import xparse for \IfNoValueTF 
\usepackage{xparse}

%Define behavior of the command with one parameter
\newcommand{\Seta}[1]{\bigl\{ #1 \bigr\}}

%Define behavior of the command with two parameter
\newcommand{\Setb}[2]{\bigl\{ #1 \bigm| #2 \bigr\}}

%Define a new command with the desired name. It checks if parameter #2 exists; 
%if no, it invokes the first command definition for single parameter (\Seta), else it invokes the \Setb
\NewDocumentCommand\Set{ m g }{
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\Seta{#1}}{\Setb{#1}{#2}}
}

\begin{document}
\[
\Set{A}{B}
\Set{A}
\]
\end{document}
```